# IntelliJ IDEA 14 | Need to VCS > Refresh File Status all the time

Tags: intellij-idea, version-control

I work with IntelliJ IDEA 14 on CentOS release 5.3 and I have an annoying phenomena - Every time I edit a file, the file itself and sometimes other files gets a gray-light-green color.
To solve to issue I have to press: VCS > Refresh File Status
I looked at Jetbrain help and file status colors, and it didn't explain why it's happening.

Comment: Which VCS are you using?

Comment: My version control system is Subversion

Comment: Have you checked your project settings for folder markup as "source" ?

Comment: Yes - The projected define these files under "sources" path

Comment: Myself and several others I work with have this same issue.  Invalidating the cache and restarting seems to fix the issue for a while, but then after a few days, week, whenever, it starts happening again.

Comment: I have the same issue on Idea 2017.1.4 running on macOS Sierra 10.12.5 and using git as VCS